# Type variable 'T' can not be resolved (with context of class com.yaml.Example)

Tags: java, generics, compilation, jackson, yaml

I'm a beginner in java generics, and I'm trying to parse my user.yaml file using generics inside my class. When i try to parse yaml file I'm getting *Type variable 'T' can not be resolved* not sure where I'm going wrong.

Initially this were just a normal class, then I implemented generics.

```java
my yaml file

user:
    name: Test User
    age: 30
```

```java
public interface IUser {
    String getName();
    IUser  setName(String name);

    Integer getAge();
    IUser setAge(Integer age);
}

public class User implements IUser{

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("age")
    private Integer age;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public User setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public User setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("name", name).append("age", age).append("additionalProperties", additionalProperties).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder().append(additionalProperties).append(age).append(name).toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((other instanceof User) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        User rhs = ((User) other);
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(additionalProperties, rhs.additionalProperties).append(age, rhs.age).append(name, rhs.name).isEquals();
    }
}
```

```java
public interface IExample {
    <T extends IUser> T getUser();
    <T extends IUser> void setUser(T user);
}

public class Example implements IExample{

    @JsonProperty("user")
    private User user;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("user")
    public <T extends IUser> T getUser() {
        return (T) user;
    }

    @JsonProperty("user")
    public <T extends IUser> void setUser(T t) {
        this.user = (User)t;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("user", user).append("additionalProperties", additionalProperties).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder().append(additionalProperties).append(user).toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((other instanceof Example) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        Example rhs = ((Example) other);
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(additionalProperties, rhs.additionalProperties).append(user, rhs.user).isEquals();
    }
}
```

```java
my main class where i'm trying to parse yaml object

public class ReadYaml {

    public void parse(){
        String path = "path/to/user.yaml";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

        try {
             IExample example = mapper.readValue(new File(path), Example.class);
             System.out.println(example.getUser().getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      new ReadYaml().parse();
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be: *Test User*, but the actual output is *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Type variable 'T' can not be resolved (with context of class com.yaml.Example)*

---

### UPDATE

```
updated yaml file

user:
    name: Test User
    age: 30
address:
    line1: bangalore
    line2: karnataka
```

```
public interface IAddress {

    String getLine1();
    IAddress setLine1(String line1);

    String getLine2();
    IAddress setLine2(String line2);
}
```

```
public class Address implements IAddress {
    // code getters and setters
}
```

```
public interface IExample<T, U extends IUser & IAddress> {
    T getUser();
    void setUser(T user);

    U getAddress();
    void setAddress(U address);
}
```

```
public class Example<T, U extends IUser & IAddress> implements IExample<T, U>{
```

```
now i'm trying to parse yaml file.
public class ReadYaml {
.
.
.

TypeReference<Example<User, Address> typeReference = new TypeReference<Example<User, Address>() {
            };
IExample example = mapper.readValue(new File(path), typeReference);
System.out.println(example.getAddress.getLine1());
```

I'm getting Error in declaration of `TypeReference<Example<User, Address> typeReference` : Type parameter 'Address' is not within its bound, Should Implement 'IUser'

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems with your code, due to [java's type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure); which requires for jackson to know **all** the concrete types to use when deserializing data. In the case of generic types, it needs to know the bounds (concrete classes for the parametrized types) of the generic classes to use. Jackson is informed of this bounds through type references; which you need to provide. Then the two problems you have are:

1. As far as I know, Jackson cannot be informed of the bounds of generic methods (and it doesn't makes much sense). So, in `Example`, the property `user` (`public <T extends IUser> void setUser(T t)`), represents an impediment, as jackson is unable to know which `T` to use to deserialize/write into.
2. The types to read into, (including the bounded ones), need to be explicitly informed to jackson, when invoking `mapper.readValue`; which is missing (you are just using `Example.class`):

   ```
    IExample example = mapper.readValue(new File(path), Example.class);
   ```

So, to solved these problems you need to change:

1. Replace the generic methods with generics classes in `IExample/Example`:

```
...
    static interface IExample<T extends IUser> {
        T getUser();
        void setUser(T user);
    }
    
    static class Example<T extends IUser> implements IExample<T> {
        
        @JsonProperty("user")
        private T user;
        @JsonIgnore
        private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        @JsonProperty("user")
        public T getUser() {
            return user;
        }
        
        @JsonProperty("user")
        public void setUser(T t) {
            this.user = t;
        }
...
```

2. Inform jackson of the `Example` bounded type by passing the appropriate jackson `TypeReference`:

```
...
    TypeReference<Example<User>> typeReference = new TypeReference<Example<User>>() { };
    IExample example = mapper.readValue(new File(path), typeReference);
...
```

Hope this helps.

**Addendum:**

The new problems you are finding, regarding the extra generic types `IAddress/Address`; are not around the `TypeReference`, which you are correctly setting as:

```
    TypeReference<Example<User, Address>> typeReference = new TypeReference<Example<User, Address>>() { };
```

The problem is with the declaration of the generic types in the interface and class.

When you say `U extends IUser & IAddress` you are saying that `U` extends/implements **BOTH** `IUser` and `IAddress`; and that's why jackson complains about `Address` not extending `IUser`; because it only extends `IAddress`. Additionally, `T` will be implicitly constrained to be capable of binding to any class extending `java.lang.Object` (and not `IUser`; which is what you may be expecting), since you didn't specify an `extends...` for it.

So, to solve this, replace the generic type declarations of `IExample` and `Example`:

```
    <T, U extends IUser & IAddress>
```

with

```
    <T extends IUser, U extends IAddress>
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56147505)

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks Marco. so i added extra objects to my yaml file.           user:
    name: Test User
    age: 30
address:
    line1: bangalore
    line2: karnataka

Comment: and when I'm trying to read the same using below  code                                                               `public interface IExample<T, U extends IUser & IAddress> {`  `public class Example<T, U extends IUser & IAddress> implements IExample<T, U>{`                                                                                                     `TypeReference<Example<User, Address>> typeReference = new TypeReference<Example<User, Address>>() {
            };        I'm getting  *Address* is not within  its bound,  should implement *IUser* `

Comment: You're welcome. Could you add these 'problematic' enhancements to the question details?

Comment: Marco, Thanks again that worked :) , Learnt something very helpful for my project :)